# Fitting large tables with equations inside

Tags: tables, equations

I am trying to insert a table which contains only equations. This is the result I obtained so far:
[image]

I was able to fit the table by using: \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}. However, as you may see the equations are not clearly visible. Is there a way to increase their size? I tried with something like \Large{} but doesn't work at all.

Thank you for you help. Any alternative solution is appreciated.

Comment: don't scale tables as you see it makes unusable inconsistent font sizes

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what your tried so far would be really helpful here. Probably you could rotate the table to a landscape orientation.

Comment: there is no point making the font size larger as it just makes adjustbox scale the result down more. are you sure that it will be readable to have that many columns? you may need to re-arrange the data to have less text on a line, and take more lines or more pages to fit, but you have given no example or indication of your page size.

Comment: unrelated use `\exp` for exp and `\theta` for theta don't use math italic for these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, the only way to typeset this table without using a tiny unreadable font size is to typeset in landscape mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,array,amsmath,amssymb}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}} % automatic display-style math mode

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the amount of intercolunn whitespace
\caption{The most important Archimedean copulas\strut}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}{C} }
\toprule
Copula 
& $Bivariate copula $ C_{\theta}(u,v) 
& $Parameter $ \theta
& $Kendall's $ \tau
& $Generator $ \psi^{}_{\theta}(t) 
& \begin{tabular}{c}Generator \\ inverse\end{tabular}\  \psi^{-1}_{\theta}(t)  \\
\midrule
Clayton 
& \max\Bigl[ \bigl(u^{-\theta}+v^{-\theta}-1\bigr)^{-1/\theta}, 0 \Bigr]
& \theta\in[-1,\infty)\setminus\{0\}
& \frac{\theta}{\theta+2}
& \frac{1}{\theta}(t^{-\theta}-1)
& (1+\theta t)^{1/\theta}\\ 
\addlinespace[5mm]
Frank  
& -\frac{1}{\theta}\ln\biggl[1+ 
\frac{(\exp(-\theta u)-1)(\exp(-\theta v)-1)}{\exp(-\theta)-1}\biggr]
& \theta\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} 
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  \\
\addlinespace[5mm]
Gumbel 
& \exp\biggl[-\bigl((-\log(u))^{\theta}+(-\log(v))^{\theta} 
             \bigr)^{1/\theta}\biggr]
& \theta \in [1,\infty) 
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant, this totally worked. I decided to turn an entire page from vertical to horizontal, and insert the table you proposed above. It looks definitely nice! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Michael - You're most welcome!